# Cellpadding in one html table cell

Tags: html, html-table, cell

Is it possible to have cell padding in just one cell versus the whole html table?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just style the cell using CSS:

```
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <td style="padding: 50px;">cell1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>cell2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 21):

For use in styling an email it is sometimes hard to achieve padding with css if you want the mail to be consistent across email programs, especially Outlook.
If you don't want to use css, a workaround is to put a whole new table with one row and one cell in the cell that you want to apply padding to. Then apply the padding to that 'one celled' table.

In the example given in the question this would become:

```
<table border='1'>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <table cellpadding="50">
    <tr>
     <td>cell1</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>cell2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah. this is the fix we need to go with a hard face.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, if you're referring to using `<table cellpadding="0">`, as that is a table-wide setting. If you want padding to be applied to just one cell, you'll have to add a class and assign it a `padding` value that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this css.

**Table using div**

**HTML**

```
  <div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableBody">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">1</div>
            <div class="divTableCell splcell">2</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">4;</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">5</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">6;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divTable{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-footer-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}
.splcell{
     background:red;
     color:#fff;
     font-weight:bold;
     text-align:center;
     padding: 5px;
}
```

using the class 'splcell' we can style the individual cell.

```
.splcell{
       background:red;
       color:#fff;
       font-weight:bold;
       text-align:center;
    }
```